# Trouble with passing form data in AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having issues passing form values to PHP via an AJAX request. As per my code below, variables can be passed back so I suspect the issue may be with `data: $('#signup-form').serialize()`.

JS:

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.domain.com/includes/register.php",
    data: $('#signup-form').serialize(),
    success: function(data)
        {
            $('#signup-response').hide();
            $('#signup-response').fadeIn();
            $('#signup-response').html(data);
        },
    error: function()
    {
        alert("fail");
    }
})
```

Form:

```
<form id="signup-form" action="" method="POST">
    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="signupEmail" placeholder="Email address">
    <input name="password1" type="password" class="form-control" id="signupPassword" placeholder="Password">
    <input name="password2" type="password" class="form-control" id="signupPassword2" placeholder="Password">
    <select name="country" id="signupCountry" class="selectpicker">
        <option value="0">Country</option>
        <option>United States</option>
        <option>United Kingdom</option>
        <option>Canada</option>
    </select>
    <select name="gender" id="signupGender" class="selectpicker">
        <option value="0">Gender</option>
        <option>Female</option>
        <option>Male</option>
    </select>
    <button id="signup" class="btn btn-success btn-block signup" type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

register.php

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['signupEmail'];
echo "hello"; // works
echo $username; // doesn't work
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, You need to use input **name** `<input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="signupEmail" placeholder="Email address">` rather use of input field id.

```
 $username = $_POST['email'];
```

instead of

```
  $username = $_POST['signupEmail'];
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Can't believe I didn't try that! Will accept in ten.